# Remove function from the elements of an array in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am building a hangman game. I have some alphabet letters that are the wrong letters and I built an array with them.When a wrong letter is been clicked my movie clip Kremmala is moving a frame showing the hangman and the wrong letter  becomes alpha = .5. The problem is that i want after the seventh click my movie clip Kremmala to stop at frame 8 and the elements of the array not to be clickable anymore. I have trouble building the code. Every help is appreciated.

I only have this code until now:

```
    var wrongletters:Array = [a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a8,a9,a10,a11,a12,a13,a14,a15,a16,a19,a20,a21,a22,a23] 
for (var i:int= 0; i< wrongletters.length; i++) {
    wrongletters[i].buttonMode = true;
    wrongletters[i].isClicked = false;
    wrongletters[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kanoklick);
    function kanoklick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
        kremmala.nextFrame(); 
        event.target.alpha = 0.5;
        if(event.currentTarget.isClicked == false){
        clickCount ++;
        event.currentTarget.isClicked = true;
}
if(clickCount == 7){
kremmala.stop();
trace("All buttons have been clicked");
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways:

1) Disabling the control (list) that holds the array with all the letters. I assume there is a visible list with id="list1" that has the `wrongletters:Array` as it's dataprovider.

```
list1.enabled = false;
```

or 2) Removing the event listener.

```
for (var i:int= 0; i< wrongletters.length; i++) 
{
    wrongletters[i].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, kanoklick);
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that you remove the click interaction only from the "wrongletters" Array. The (possibly existant) "rightletters" Array can still be clicked. From my knowledge of kremala game, you would want to prevent both.

Comment: Yes I did the same with the right letters array. Thanks!